# Unable to login after delete user password

Tags: ubuntu

I used the following command to delete user password in Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo passwd -d <user_name>
```

But after that it still prompting me to enter a password, and i cant login with any password or no password.

The machine is now totally inaccessible because the user is the only user

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have other administrative accounts and, having forgotten (or delete) the password of your Linux account, you cannot log in to the operating system, then you need a single user mode to reset the password.

In single-user mode, no credentials (login, password) are asked for entry, while the logged in user has superuser rights. In this mode, using the command `passwd`, it is possible to set a new password.

https://www.vultr.com/docs/boot-into-single-user-mode-reset-root-password

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-lost-root-password-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux

Comment: you saved my life, this works like a charm, but I wonder why using `passwd -d` will disable an user account, isn't it only make the user passwordless ?

Comment: Generally speaking, no Ubuntu tools can set an empty password to a user. But, if you really want to - try https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password